# Namenode can't running

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I built a single hadoop,when I tried `./start-dfs.sh`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJbLA.png)
namenode didn't work

logs↓
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcgvv.png)

I have tried to delete tmp and initialize nanenode format `hdfs namenode -format`, but it also didn't work

50070 the port for namenode is free when i check
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ5o2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the bind address you've provided in the XML files is not valid.

Start with `0.0.0.0`, rather than `123.56.x.y`

If you need to restrict external access to the service, then use OS firewall settings, rather than Hadoop configs

Comment: I think I confused private address with public address. I changed ip to my private address now and it worked. however thank you for your answer!!